# Do I need to increment the Room Database version number if I only changed the DAO's, not the entities?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I was just wondering if you **really need to increment** the room database version number if you changed only the Data Access Objects (DAO's).

So the scenario is:

1. I already published the app in the Play Store with version x
2. I only changed part of some DAO's without changing the entities themselves
3. I incremented the app version code and name (maybe unrelated)

Do I need to increment the room database version number?

Comment: *Do I need to increment the room database version number?*: **NO**

Comment: this is also something you should be able to test yourself: with your current version, change the dao's and run the app again with new dao's and see if you get an exception :)

Comment: @md-asaduzzaman **THANKS** hehe

Comment: @a-local-nobody Yeah, I tried it but just wanted to make sure. I could not find it in Android's own documentation so I had second thoughts. 

Thanks for the quick feedback everyone I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to increment the room database version number?

You need to increment the schema version when you change the schema. Simply adding functions to a DAO should not result in a schema change. However, your schema might change by things beyond your DAO and your entities. Right now, I think only `@DatabaseView` would have that effect in terms of annotations, and I do not see anything in `RoomDatabase.Builder` that should have an effect (other than `addMigrations()`, which specifically is for version number changes).

Comment: Thank you very much its been bugging me this whole time if I am to increment it or not. I only wanted to verify since one wrong move on my part and I have a build that crashes.